# What are standard unicode fonts?

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts

What are standard unicode fonts for following operating systems:

- Windows XP
- Windows Vista
- Window 7

By standard I mean they are present in fresh installation of OS - there is no need to install them as additional package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the list by product from links;

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/default.aspx

[www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/winxp.htm](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/winxp.htm)

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for the same thing. Looks like there is only one font in all Win OS :

**Lucida Sans Unicode**

File name: l_10646.ttf

Designed for: Latin;Greek;Cyrillic;Hebrew

List of supported :

```
Product Name                Font Version

BackOffice Server 4.0           0.98
Office Mac 2008                 5.00
Plus 95                         0.98
Windows 2000                    2.00
Windows 7                       5.00
Windows 8                       5.00
Windows 98                      0.98
Windows 98 Second Edition       0.98
Windows NT Terminal Server 4.0  0.98
Windows NT Workstation 3.5      0.98
Windows NT Workstation 4.0      0.98
Windows NT Workstation 4.0 SP4  2.00
Windows NT Workstation 4.0 SP5  2.00
Windows NT Workstation 4.0b     0.98
Windows Server 2003             2.00
Windows Server 2008             5.00
Windows Vista                   5.00
Windows XP                      2.00
Windows XP SP2                  2.00
Works 4.5a                      0.98
Works 9                         2.01
```

Resource : [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1263)